# R workplace in terminal Linux

Tags: r, linux, ssh, terminal, centos

We got CentOS Linux server with terminal access only (no GUI). It is behind a firewall (no Internet connection). The only ways to access it is SSH and FTP. We have root access through sudo.

I need to setup R workplace there to run long-running multi-core R tasks (from few hours to few days). What are the best tools and tips to start with?

We have RStudio web-interface installed - but I feel like it might be not reliable for long-running tasks - because I need to keep a session. Maybe I am wrong.

More specific questions:

1) What is the best way to install packages? (I currently use miniCran but suspect there might be a better way).

2) What is the best way to keep several terminals with running tasks? (screen?)

3) What is the best terminal editor for R scripts that allows executing what you type line-by-line just as we do in RStudio? (is there any at all?)

Disclaimer: I don't have much of Linux experience but willing to learn.

Thank you!

Comment: That’s a lot of questions bundled into one …

Answer (score 1):

1. > What is the best way to install packages?

   The only currently existing one I know is miniCRAN. It doesn’t seem to be too bad. But keep an eye on the work by Gábor Csárdi, especially [cranlike](https://github.com/r-hub/cranlike).
2. > What is the best way to keep several terminals with running tasks?

   [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki). It’s a modern “screen” replacement, and better in every way, especially with a configuration such as [`.tmux`](https://github.com/gpakosz/.tmux) by Gregory Pakosz.
3. > What is the best terminal editor for R scripts that allows executing what you type line-by-line just as we do in RStudio?

   [Nvim-R](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R) if you’re using Vim, or [ESS](https://ess.r-project.org/) if you’re using Emacs. I use Nvim-R every day, both when working on a cluster and on my desktop computer. I also recommend a better autocompletion. Personally I use [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe). There are other, supposedly better alternatives, but I could never get those to work.

   That said, I’d generally recommend *not* executing commands interactively. Write standalone scripts and execute those.

Comment: Thank you, Konrad! That helps a lot!